# When does compactness imply sequential compactness?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

It is well known that if $ X $ is a metric space then sequential compactness and compactness are equivalent.

Now we consider a normed vector space $ E $ and its dual $ E^\ast $. From Banach Alauglou theorem we know that the closed unit ball in $ E^\ast $ is compact in the weak $ \ast $ topology. Moreover this topology is not metrizable in general. So it is natural to ask:

Is this ball also sequentially compact in the weak $ \ast $ topology?  How can I prove it?

In general, when does compactness imply sequential compactness? (I'm loooking for some results about it)

Thanks

Comment: No: see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/27439/12042) to an earlier question. Specifically, the unit ball in $\ell^{\infty*}$ is not sequentially compact.

Comment: For a Banach space $X$: see the first answer to Brian's link for a sufficient condition ($X$ is separable). Another sufficient condition is that $X^*$ does not contain a copy of $\ell_1$.  Also of interest is the following result of Edward Odell and Haskel Rosenthal: If $X$ is separable, then the unit ball of the second dual of $X$ is weak$*$ sequentially compact if and only if $X$ contains no isomorph of $\ell_1$. This result is contained in Joseph Diestel's Sequences and Series in Banach Spaces.