# Example of normed linear space with bounded sequence in dual having no weak* convergent subsequence

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, dual-spaces

If $X$ is a separable normed linear space, then we know that every bounded sequence in $X^*$ has a weak-* convergent subsequence . Can we drop the separability condition , i.e. if we don't assume $X$ is separable, then are there counterexamples ?

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: There are counterexamples; see page 226 [here](https://archive.org/stream/springer_10.1007-978-1-4612-5200-9/10.1007-978-1-4612-5200-9#page/n235/mode/2up) for example.

Comment: @David Mitra : What is meant by $l_1(\mathbb R)$ on the book ? Isn't it kind of contradictory as I thought $l_1$ is separable ...

Comment: The space of absolutely convergent sums, indexed by $\Bbb R$; so elements are of the form $\sum_{r\in\Bbb R} x_r$.

Comment: See also, the second answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27423/compactness-in-the-weak-topology).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $X=l^\infty$, which is not separable. Define the sequence $f_n$ in $(l^\infty)^*$ by
$$
f_n (x) = x_n.
$$
Then $(f_n)$ is a bounded sequence, in fact, $\|f_n\|_{(l^\infty)^*}=1$.

However, it does not have a weak-star converging subsequence. Let $(f_{n_k})$ denote a subsequence. Then define $x\in l^\infty$ by
$$
x_{n_k}=(-1)^k,
$$
set all other entries $x_i=0$. Then 
$$
f_{n_k}(x) = (-1)^k,
$$
which is not convergent.

Comment: Of course, by Alaoglu's theorem. This shows that a *subnet* of a *sequence* isn't a  *subsequence*.