# Compact imply sequential compactness on sequences?

Tags: general-topology, banach-spaces, compactness

Let $Q=\{q_1,q_2,\dots,q_n,\dots\}$ be a set included in the dual of a Banach space $X^*$. If we know that $\overline{Q}$ is compact in the weak* topology, is it true that $\overline{Q}$ is sequentially compact in the same topology?

I know that if $X$ is separable then compactness is equivalent to sequential compactness.

Generally, it is well-known that the two concepts are independent. My question is if they coincide on particular sets, like Q. So for countable sets that are relatively compact.

I have tried to use the definition of compact sets with nets. I think that this one is the best for this problem.

Comment: Weak* topology is only defined on a dual space.

Comment: You are right. I have modified the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compactness in the weak\* topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27423/compactness-in-the-weak-topology)

Comment: No. It is well-known that the two concepts are independent. My question is if they coincide on particular sets, like $Q$. So for countable sets...

Comment: @MaximDiana: But an answer to your question follows essentially immediately, because if you have any compact but not sequentially compact $K\subset X^*$, just take $Q$ to be a sequence in $K$ with no convergent subsequence.

Comment: How can you construct such a sequence?

Comment: By the definition of a not sequentially compact space, $K$ has such a sequence.